# How to disable momentum in specific layer in tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, gradient-descent

I have a neural network with three hidden layers, which can be trained with "pure" gradient descent or with some more sophisticated techniques. I also noticed that in the my problem momentum-based optimization methods (adam, adadelta, momentum) works much better.

Now to the interesting part. By design, I want to disable momentum in the first layer of the NN. That means, I want to update weights with Adam in second and third layers, but use simple gradient descent in first layer.

Of course, I can always write my own optimizer: calculate gradients with `tf.gradients(loss, tf.trainable_variables())` and then just do the momentum trick myself. But it would be nice to have option to use special optimizer parameters in every layer. Have anybody heard about the way to do such thing?

Comment: How do you define the layers in your network?

Comment: Nothing special, i think ```W_1 = tf.Variable(
            tf.truncated_normal([HIDDEN_0_SIZE, HIDDEN_1_SIZE],
                                stddev=1/np.sqrt(HIDDEN_0_SIZE)),
            name='W')
        b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([HIDDEN_1_SIZE]), name='b')
        hidden_1 = tf.matmul(activation_0_drop, W_1) + b_1
        activation_1 = tf.nn.relu(hidden_1, name='activation')

        activation_1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(activation_1, keep_prob)```   Don't know why, markdown drops all the new lines :(

Comment: It just doesn't work with comments, if you edit the post, the new lines will be there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can provide the list of variables to optimize to the optimizer ([docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer)):

```
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
opt_op = opt.minimize(loss, var_list=[W1, b1])
opt2 = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
opt2_op = opt2.minimize(loss, var_list=[W2, b2])
```

You will have to extract the variable list (probably weights and biases) of a given layer yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! But in such way I can disable training at all in the first layer by not providing it to the optimizer. But I still want to train it, but with usage of momentum. Maybe I can have two optimizers: GradientDescent for the first layer and Adam for everything else.

Comment: See the edit. If you define two optimizers, each one can update the corresponding variables. And if you run them together in a `sess.run([opt_op, opt2_op])`, I'd _suspect_ that the gradients will be calculated only once.